# How to change the "link" parameter on a Facebook page graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

How can one change the opengraph link value on a Facebook page (type: website) from

https://www.facebook.com/yourwebsite to http://www.yourwebsite.com

It seems easier than it is. I couldn't find an answer. Seems it has something to do with adding an app, and then?!

Example: http://graph.facebook.com/anguillabeachescom

Answer (score 0):

I can’t see that being done anywhere on the page’s settings interface.

My guess would be you have to [claim your domain](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/) with Facebook to make things work this way (and maybe have to have a special category set for your Facebook page – the example page you mentioned is of type “website”.)

Comment: Thanks. Have tried that but didn't work. The interest on this is that one can have have real links with anchor keyword text from inside Facebook!